# Latex - Appendix on seperate page in table of content

Tags: latex

I create my table of contents with `\tableofcontents` . It also shows an appendix table of contents, but i want it to be displayed on a new page (like inserting `\newpage` between the last entry of the normal toc and the appendix toc). Is there a practical way of achieving that?

Working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.
  
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...
   
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Section}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\section{Second Section}
   
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\appendix
\part{Appendix}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...
     
\end{document}
```

I want a new page below the red line

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\addtocontents{toc}{\clearpage}` to smuggle a page break into the toc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.
  
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...
   
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Section}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\section{Second Section}
   
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\clearpage}
\part{Appendix}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...
     
\end{document}
```

If this does not work, try `\addtocontents{toc}{\newpage}` instead.

Comment: I needed to youse \newpage, but it worked like a charm. thank you!